# SwiftUI: make @ObservedObject var optional?

Tags: ios, swiftui

In a view, I have something like this:

```
struct DriverView: View {

    @ObservedObject var car:Car?

    .....
}
```

I get this error:

`Generic struct 'ObservedObject' requires that 'Car?' conform to 'ObservableObject'.`

`car` is a NSManagedObject:

```
public class Car: NSManagedObject { }
```

if I remove the optional:

```
@ObservedObject var car:Car
```

the error goes away.

The problem is that I may not have a car entity to set in the `DriverView` at times.

How can I make `car` optional?

Comment: You cannot, Optional is a value type, instead refactor to avoid this case, eg. separated dedicated view with non-optional car and create that view in body conditionally when car is present.

Comment: took me a while, but, I've now changed my "thinking" to what you said here. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't init a `DriverView` if you don't have a `car` to pass in. This can be done with an `if` in the body of the parent View which generates a `_ConditionalView`.

Note, since you are passing in a car we would normally name this a `CarView`.